# Are CDI Events available across classloaders

Tags: cdi

I have a fairly straight forward question. Lets say my Application A delegates its payment call to another Application B. There is some post payment Fulfillment that needs to be done by Application A. Both applications are separate EARs. Is it possible for an Application B to fire a CDI event that is Observed by Application A. Also the Payment app is used by a lot of other Applications that too would need to listen to events of interest to them. How would you filter to make sure that an Application Z will not try and catch the event meant for application A. I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight forward answer: No. Neither events, nor beans are accessible to different classloaders. In Seam 3 the solution we had was to bridge events over JMS. I'm pretty sure that's possible with the new JMS specs and implementations.

Comment: Oh I would not be so fast ;)
USUALLY this is true. But if you think about having an EAR with AppA and AppB inside it and they both have their @ApplicationScopeds bean in the shared ear/lib THEN it will be possible. In that case your AppB bean observer in such a shared lib will get the event fired by AppA even if they have different WebApp ClassLoaders (but the SAME shared ear lib ClassLoader). But in general Jason is absolutely right at least when it comes to unrelated apps. They don't see anything from each other.

Comment: Thanks Mark! EARs are a completely different pile of mud when it comes to CDI :) Lots of things work the same, some don't.